# How can I have in a __m128 variable a whole complex number?

Tags: c, x86, simd, complex-numbers, intrinsics

I don't have too much experience using intrinsics in C. My problem is having this function

```
void function(complex float* A, complex float* B, complex float alpha) {
```

I want to use alpha like `__m128`, but if I do this

```
__m128 alfa = _mm_load_ps((float const *)&alpha);
```

alfa only gets the real part of the complex number.

How can I have in `__m128 alfa` the whole complex number?

Answer (score 1):

This code worked fine for me:

```
complex float a __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = 5 + 10*I;
__m128 f = _mm_load_ps((float const *)&a); // requires 16B alignment
float *p = (float *)&f;
printf("real(0): %f, imag(1): %f, (2): %f, (3): %f\n", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);
```

prints

```
real(0): 5.000000, imag(1): 10.000000, (2): 0.000000, (3): 0.000000
```

Are you sure `alpha` has a non-zero imaginary part? How do you know you are only getting the real part?

Comment: I have try this complex float alphaA __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = alpha;

Comment: followed by this expression __m128 alfa = _mm_load_ps((float const *)&alphaA); but I get this with your print: real(0): 0.335223, imag(1): -0.911647, (2): 0.335223, (3): -0.911647. The thing is that I want to multiply 2 complex numbers so I think that's the way to do it. Do you have any idea of how do the multiplication?

Comment: what value does alpha have?

Comment: @CSR95: Did you try letting the compiler auto-vectorize the multiply by using the regular `*` C operator?  That's kind of the point of having a `complex` type instead of making you define your own structs.  (C essentially comes with operator-overloaded complex-number types).  Clang is more aggressive about auto-vectorization that requires some shuffling, like this will.  gcc might do each one separately.  If you're going to use SIMD for operating on many complex numbers in parallel, store the real and imaginary parts in separate arrays.